# AutoMapper mapping between enum and its integer values fails with ReverseMap

Tags: c#, enums, mapping, automapper, automapper-10

The application is built with DDD approach, with a separate set of persistence models. I called database object, or dbo:

```cs
public class ParentDbo
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDbo
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public ParentDbo Parent { get; set; }
    public int RetryNumber { get; set; }
}
```

We have a simple model to look at: a parent and a child relationship. The `RetryNumber` presents the enum value in the database.

On retrieving data, it uses Dapper to first query the database, and use its `splitOn` feature to map data into them. This part is irrelevant but I will show it anyway for completeness:

```cs
const string sql = "SELECT * FROM XXX ....";

using (var cnt = _dbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
{
    var childDbos = await cnt.QueryAsync<ChildDbo, ParentDbo, ChildDbo>(
        sql: sql,
        map: (childDbo, parentDbo) =>
        {
            childDbo.Parent = parentDbo;
            return childDbo;
        },
        splitOn: "ParentId"
    );
}
```

Dapper has limitation that it couldn't map data to **private complex** objects. That's mainly the reason why I have to have 2 sets of models. I would like to encapsulate the data and logic within domain models, with private setters and other techniques.

Here are my domain models:

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int TypeId { get; private set; }
    
    public Parent(int parentId, int typeId)
    {
        // Validations
        
        this.Id = parentId;
        this.TypeId = typeId;
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }
    public Attempt Attempt { get; private set; }
    
    public Child(int childId, Parent parent, Attempt attempt)
    {
        // Validations
        
        this.Id = childId;
        this.Parent = parent;
        this.Attempt = attempt;
    }
}
```

For domain models, I don't want public setters, and parameter-less constructors.

The `Attempt` is the enum with integer backing values:

```cs
public enum Attempt
{
    Original = 1,
    FirstRetry = 2,
    SecondRetry = 3,
    LastRetry = 4
}
```

Lastly, I want to use AutoMapper to map between Dbos and the domain models. Here is the mapping:

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Child, ChildDbo>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RetryNumber, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (int)src.Attempt))
            .ReverseMap();
        
        CreateMap<Parent, ParentDbo>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I want to have two-ways mappings so I use `ReverseMap()`.

**.Net Fiddle demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/saEHWd

It maps domain models to dbos without problem:

[image]

But its reverse, mapping from dbos to domain models, is throwing exceptions:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Program+Child needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. (Parameter 'type')
> at lambda_method18(Closure , Object , Child , ResolutionContext )
> at AutoMapper.Mapper.MapCore[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, IMemberMap memberMap)
> at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source, TDestination destination)
> at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)
> at Program.Main()

I've tried to remove the enum property and everything worked so I'm pretty sure it's the enum mapping that's having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in your fiddle you are trying to map from `ChildDbo` to `Parent` and there is no mapping setup for it. Change the mapping code to:

```
var child2 = mapper.Map<Child>(childDbo);
```

And since there is mismatch in third `Child`'s ctor param and source property names change map to:

```
CreateMap<Child, ChildDbo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.RetryNumber, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (int)src.Attempt))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ConstructUsing((dbo, ctx) => new Child(dbo.ChildId, ctx.Mapper.Map<Parent>(dbo.Parent), (Attempt)dbo.RetryNumber));
```

See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AU6S7g)

Or rename third `Child`'s ctor parameter to `retryNumber`:

```
public Child(int childId, Parent parent, Attempt retryNumber)
```

see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CTnyW8).

or use [`ForCtorParam`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html#construction):

```
CreateMap<Child, ChildDbo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.RetryNumber, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => (int)src.Attempt))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForCtorParam("attempt", opt => opt.MapFrom(dbo => dbo.RetryNumber))
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gM83cG).

Comment: The map from ChildDbo to Parent was a typo, but man thanks a lot for helping out. I thought AutoMapper was smart enough to figure out `RetryNumber` will map to `Attempt` because I've supplied the mapping before `ReverseMap`.